# How can I cleanly write abstractions for interacting with RESTful resources?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, rest

I have a simple REST client that works well.  In my application code I do something like this:

```
restClient = new RestClient(configurationData)
restClient.get('/person/1') //Get Person
restClient.get('/equipment/auto/3') //Get an Auto
restClient.get('/house/7') //Get a House
```

That works well but things are getting more complicated and I would like to divorce the application code from the specific resource locations.

I'd like to be able to write a wrapper around the service, which will store the resource locations and not require me to put them in my application code.  I would expect my code to start looking more like this:

```
restClient = new RestClient(configurationData)
restClient.getPerson(1) //Get Person
restClient.getAuto(3) //Get an Auto
restClient.getHouse(7) //Get a House
```

I started adding these wrappers inside of my `RestClient` class but it got very bloated very fast, and it felt that the abstraction should be at a higher level.  Mixing Resource-specifics with my client also felt wrong.

So, instead I subclassed `RestClient`, and each resource has its own class.  The problem is that now I have to instantiate a new client for every different resource type:

```
personRestClient = new PersonRestClient(configurationData)
personRestClient.get(1);
autoRestClient = new AutoRestClient(configurationData)
autoRestClient.get(3);
housesRestClient = new HousesRestClient(configurationData)
housesRestClient.get(7);
```

But now I've created a new `Client` class for each `Resource` and I am fairly certain that is a very bad thing to do.  It's also a pain because I have to tie my connection configuration data to each one, when this should only happen once.

Is there a good example or pattern I should be following when I want to write abstractions for my Resources?  My base `RestClient` works fine but I dislike having to put the server-side API locations in my application code.  But I also don't want to have to instantiate one specialized client class for each Resource I want to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation, and have what I consider to be a good implementation with the appropriate abstractions. Whether my solution is the best practice or not, I cannot guarantee it, but it is fairly lightweight. Here is how I have it architected:

My UI layer needs to make calls into my REST service, so I created an abstraction called ServiceManagers.Interfaces.IAccountManager. The interface has methods called GetAccounts(Int64 userId).

Then I created a Rest.AccountManager that implemented this Interface, and injected that into my AccountController. The Rest.AccountManager is what wraps the REST specifics (URL, get/post/put..., parameters, etc).

So, now my UI code only has to call accountManager.GetAccounts(userId). You can create an all-encompassing interface so that you only have a Get, but I feel that is less expressive. It is ok to have many different interfaces for each component(ie: PersonManager, HouseManager, AutoManager), because each are a separate concern returning different data. Do not be afraid of having a lot of interfaces and classes, as long as your names are expressive.

In my example, my UI has a different manager for each controller, and the calls made fit each controller appropriately (ie. GetAccounts for AccountController, GetPeople for PeopleController).

Also, as to the root configuration data, you can just use a configurationCreationFactory class or something. That way all implementations have the appropriate configuration with the core logic in one location.

This can be a hard thing to explain, and I know I did not do a perfect job, but hopefully this helps a little. I will try to go back through and clean it up later, especially if you do not get my point :)

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking something like this, again some way of mapping your end points to the client. You can have the mapping as an xml or a properties file which can be loaded and cached during the app start. The file should have key value pairs
PERSON_ENDPOINT=/person/
AUTO_ENDPOINT=/equipment/auto/...
The client should pass this key to the factory may be ClientFactory which has this xml cache and retrieves the end point from the cached file. The parameters can be passed to the factory as custom object or a map. The factory gives back the complete end point say "/person/1" which you can pass to your client. This way you dont need to have different classes for the client. If you dont like the xml or a file you can have it as a static map with key value pairs. If its an xml or file you dont need a code change every time that is the advantage. 
Hope this helps you.